# Cannot login to Windows 7 because of missing keyboard layout

Tags: windows-7, passwords, login, keyboard-layout

Recently one of my friend change the password of his Windows 7, which contains Arabic alphabets. And he mistakenly removed the Arabic language from keyboard layout. So he is stuck behind the Windows 7 welcome screen. Because he cannot enter the password (which contain Arabic characters).

Note: he knows the password, he has no password reset disk.*

How can these characters be typed?  Or how can the layout be changed?

Comment: what special characters (Arabic characters) do you need for the password ?

Comment: something like گ.

Comment: If you press Alt + (Number), like for exampe Alt+1447=º  you get Ascii characters. Maybe there is a way also to get your arabic special character this way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With a deep Google search, found a solution - [KonBoot](http://www.thelead82.com/products.html) can bypass Windows based OS using BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD to enable administrator user
Type

```vbs
Net user administrator /active:yes
```

Change keyboard language add Arabic make sure you don't select us in Arabic language